# Counter JS issue , doesn't toggle class every 1s

Tags: javascript, toggle, setinterval

Counter doesn't work properly . I would like to get result when counterFun function toggle .active class and show number in  every 1s. For now class is toggled but  shows every 2nd number and it doesn't looks like it happen every 1sek

```js
let clickNumber = 0;
const time = 1000;
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



function counterFun() {
    clickNumber++;
    h1.textContent = clickNumber;
    h1.classList.toggle('active');

    console.log(clickNumber);
}
setInterval(counterFun, time);
```

```css
.regular {
  opacity: 0;
}

 .active {
   font-size: 100px;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div>
    <h1 class="regular active">0</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are using .toggle which doesn't toggle again until the second iteration. So basically  you end up with:

0 - toggle
1 - off
2 - toggle
3 - off

Your options are to either use .remove and .add for the class or add a second .toggle.

Example with remove:

```js
let clickNumber = 0;
const time = 1000;
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



function counterFun() {
   h1.classList.remove('active');
    clickNumber++;
    h1.textContent = clickNumber;
    h1.classList.add('active');
    console.log(clickNumber);
}
setInterval(counterFun, time);
```

```css
.regular {
  opacity: 0;
}

 .active {
   font-size: 100px;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div>
    <h1 class="regular active">0</h1>
</div>
```

Example with Toggle:

```js
let clickNumber = 0;
const time = 1000;
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



function counterFun() {
    h1.classList.toggle('active');
    clickNumber++;
    h1.textContent = clickNumber;
    h1.classList.toggle('active');
    console.log(clickNumber);
}
setInterval(counterFun, time);
```

```css
.regular {
  opacity: 0;
}

 .active {
   font-size: 100px;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div>
    <h1 class="regular active">0</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you need to remove and add the class at the same time, you can use this code

```js
let clickNumber = 0;
const time = 1000;
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');



function counterFun() {

    $("#demo").addClass("active").delay(800).queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        clickNumber++;
        h1.textContent = clickNumber;
        next();
    });

    console.log(clickNumber);
}
setInterval(counterFun, time);
```

```css
.regular {
  opacity: 0;
}

 .active {
   font-size: 100px;
   opacity: 1;
   transition-delay: .4s;
   transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="regular active" id="demo">0</h1>
 </div>
```

PS: you need jquery

Comment: They do not need JQuery. Anything you can do with JQuery you can do without. No sense in recommending a lib they are not already using.

Comment: @basic ok, i know, but is for shorting the code, i don't see a big problem